# WD Blue HDD is making strange noises

Tags: hard-drive, sata, noise

I recently purchased a WD Blue WD20EZBX HDD. I already have a 1TB 7200 RPM WD Blue in my PC, and I never heard any annoying noises from it, so I hoped this would be the same. However, the new HDD is sporadically making very strange, pulsing noises even though it is not under load. I tried to record it: https://sndup.net/99st
Unfortunatly it did not come out very well, but you should still be able to hear it. Does anyone have a clue what could be causing this annoying noise?

Comment: If it's new, RMA it.

Comment: It is new. Do you think this noise is so unusual that it would be a RMA reason?

Comment: It's not worth the risk. It could operate for 6 months fine, then just give up on you. If you tell the vendor the drive is faulty, they will replace it. They'll just RMA it back to the manufacturer.

Comment: Might perhaps be [Coil Whine](https://www.howtogeek.com/297166/what-is-coil-whine-and-can-i-get-rid-of-it-on-my-pc/).

Answer (score 0):

That just sounds like the default electrical hum of an HDD. It doesn't have to be under load to have it be reading files off of itself (like opening dialogues and the File Explorer). Generally, that hum is just it reading/writing small caches and system dialogues that need to be loaded. HDDs work by spinning disks and putting down an arm to tap magnetic 1's and 0's into the machine, as well as read them.
TL;DR: It's the normal hum of reading system files. You could return it or ignore it, but it doesn't strike me as odd.

Comment: Well, what I find odd about it is that the drive is actually relatively silent most of the time, and about once in 30min, this noise appears for about 30 seconds. And it is much louder than the normal "load" sound when I am copying files to the HDD.

Comment: It could just be the way the drive is built. If it's really concerning, I would return it like @spikey_richie said